# Why is it whenever I use scandir() I receive periods at the beginning of the array?

Tags: php, directory

Why is it whenever I use scandir() I receive periods at the beginning of the array?

```
Array
(
    [0] => .
    [1] => ..
    [2] => bar.php
    [3] => foo.txt
    [4] => somedir
)
Array
(
    [0] => somedir
    [1] => foo.txt
    [2] => bar.php
    [3] => ..
    [4] => .
)
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Those are the current (`.`) and parent (`..`) directories. They are present in all directories, and are used to refer to the directory itself and its direct parent.

Answer (score 127):

There are two entries present in every directory listing:

- `.` refers to the current directory
- `..` refers to the parent directory (or the root, if the current directory is the root)

You can remove them from the results by filtering them out of the results of scandir:

```
$allFiles = scandir(__DIR__); // Or any other directory
$files = array_diff($allFiles, array('.', '..'));
```

Comment: Nice.  This can also be condensed into one line: `$files = array_diff(scandir(__DIR__), array('.', '..'));` (see  http://www.electrictoolbox.com/php-scandir-find-files/).

Comment: I would like to note that, should you care about the indexing of $files, Dan Bray's answer is definitely worth looking at. I only wish I had scrolled down another half page earlier!

Answer (score 15):

To remove `.` and `..` from `scandir` use this function:

```
function scandir1($dir)
{
    return array_values(array_diff(scandir($dir), array('..', '.')));
}
```

The `array_values` command re-indexes the array so that it starts from 0. If you don't need the array re-indexing, then the accepted answer will work fine. Simply: `array_diff(scandir($dir), array('..', '.'))`.

Comment: holy cow, why did I not scroll down more, earlier? this is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 8):

In one line of code:

```
$files=array_slice(scandir('/path/to/directory/'), 2);
```

Comment: This can cause problems if you have other files which are sorted before `.` and `..`. It's quite uncommon, as I think only `-` sorts before `.` and is valid in a filename, but it's worth remembering.

Answer (score 3):

In Unix convention . is a link to the current directory while .. is a link to the parent directory. Both of them exist as a file in the directory index.

Comment: Can you quote a source that says this is a UNIX convention? DOS and Windows have `.` and `..` too, don't they?

Comment: Windows has those too, it's not specific to Unix.

Comment: It's a Unix convention; that doesn't prevent it from being a DOS and Windows convention too.

Comment: OK I would take that back. Both Windows and Unix use that convention. I only have the perception that most PHP server runs on Unix-based systems.

Answer (score 2):

another one-line code solution to filter dots out

```
$files = array_filter(scandir($directory), function($file) {return strlen($file) > 2;});
```