# php - listing folders and files in a directory

Tags: php

hi there i am using the following function to list all the files and folders in a directory.

```
<?php

  function listFolderFiles($dir){

        $ffs = scandir($dir);

            foreach($ffs as $ff){

                echo $ff . "<br/>";

            }

    }

?>
```

but the problem seems to be i'm getting all the folders in the directory alright but i'm also getting a `.` and a `..`. something like the one below.

```
.
..
direc
img
music
New Text Document.txt
```

and i am using the following function like: `listFolderFiles('MyFolder');`

what i want to do is get all the folders and files but not the `.` and the `..`, what have i done wrong and how can i get what i want. thanks!

Comment: you haven't done anything wrong, do you know what the `.` and `..` are ?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7132399/why-is-it-whenever-i-use-scandir-i-receive-periods-at-the-beginning-of-the-arr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy way to get rid of the dots that `scandir()` picks up in Linux environments:

```
<?php
$ffs = array_diff(scandir($dir), array('..', '.'));
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use glob quite easily, which puts the filenames into an array:

```
print_r(glob("*.*"));
```

example:

```
// directory name
$directory = "/";

// get in directory
$files = glob($directory . "*");

$d = 0; // init dir array count
$f = 0; // init file array count

// directories and files
foreach($files as $file) { 
    if(is_dir($file)) {
        array($l['directory'][$d] =  $file);
        $d++;
    } else {
        array($l['file'][$f] = $file);
        $f++;
    }
}

print_r($l);
```

**NOTE**: `scandir` will also pick up hidden files such as `.htaccess`, etc. That is why the glob method should be considered instead, unless of course you want to show them.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it!

```
<?php

function listFolderFiles($dir){
    $ffs = scandir($dir);
    foreach($ffs as &$ff){

        if ($ff != '.' && $ff != '..') {
            echo $ff . "<br/>";
        }
    }
}

?>
```