# How to build an indexed array of .html filenames that exist in a directory?

Tags: php, arrays, directory, filenames, preg-grep

I am using this php code to get all html-files in the given directory:

```
$dirpath = ".....";
$filelist = preg_grep('~\.(html)$~', scandir($dirpath));
```

Now I want to get a specific element in the array, for example:

```
echo $filelist[0];
```

This fails. In my directory there are 52 files, and `count($filelist)` returns '52', but to get the first element I need to use `echo $filelist[3];` The last item gets addresses by the index 54. What is this? Why do I can't adress them with index 0-51?

Edit: Possible duplicate only explains the shift of 2 indexes, what is the third? However: `array_values` solved the problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is it whenever I use scandir() I receive periods at the beginning of the array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7132399/why-is-it-whenever-i-use-scandir-i-receive-periods-at-the-beginning-of-the-arr)

Comment: `$filelist = array_values(array_diff(scandir($dirpath), ['.','..']));`  For [Example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3ab1f6ed317cf4ce9cf277c234c50ff86f8b8fd8)  It's probably a bad practice to mix file types in the same Dir, such as `.html` and `.css` in the same place.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix `glob()` is the one-call solution.

Comment: @mickmackusa - I know what it is ... but strangely I never used it before.  I don't use scandir much (not in the last 5 years).  Mainly I use SPL classes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`array_values()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) function to reset the numeric index to start from 0.

Try:

```
$dirpath = ".....";
$filelist = array_values(preg_grep('~\.(html)$~', scandir($dirpath)));

// print the first value
echo $filelist[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

Those are the current (.) and parent (..) directories. They are present in all directories, and are used to refer to the directory itself and its direct parent.
[Why is it whenever I use scandir() I receive periods at the beginning of the array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7132399/why-is-it-whenever-i-use-scandir-i-receive-periods-at-the-beginning-of-the-arr)

Comment: What question are you answering?

Answer (score 1):

Just use

```
$filelist = array_values($filelist);
```

Your function is cherry picking the items from an already indexed array, so the keys are not in sequence.

Answer (score 0):

Using `scandir()` then applying a regex filter, then re-indexing is an inefficient approach, when `glob()` can deliver what you want in one call.

The following will generate an array of only .html files.

If you want to see the dirpath prepended to the filename:

```
$filelist = glob($dirpath . "*.html");  // you may need to add a slash before the filename
```

If you want to see only the filenames:

```
chdir($dirpath);
$filelist = glob("*.html");
```